# Cargar un model con un JsonResult C#

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc

En un método **JsonResult** estoy retornado una lista `return Json(listarPapeleta);` y está lista la quiero cargar como `@model` de la página.

En palabras mas sencillas que `return Json(listarPapeleta);` funcione como un `return View(listarPapeleta);`

Se puede hacer de alguna forma?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear el siguiente método en una clase Base de Controladores:

```
public static string RenderViewToString(ControllerContext context, string viewName, object model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        viewName = context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

    var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);
    var tempData = context.Controller.TempData;

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(context, viewName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(context, viewResult.View, viewData, tempData, sw);

        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

Luego, en tu controller realizas lo siguiente:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult RetornarLista()
{
    return Json(new
    {
        Vista = BaseController.RenderViewToString(ControllerContext, "_Grid", listarPapeleta)
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Donde "_Grid" es una vista parcial que recibe tu modelo de lista.

En tu javascript utiliza, por ejemplo:

```
$("#DivDelGrid").html(respuestaJson.Vista);
```

Obviamente debes adecuarlo a lo que necesitas, espero que te sirva.